# php RegexIterator / Recursive Iterator - can't search file with accents

Tags: php, file, search, utf-8, iterator

I have a script that will search for a file inside all directories of my server, then return the full path to the file. The search query comes encoded in base64.

The script works perfectly when searching a file without accents. But as soon as i search for something with accents, it won't work.

Here is my file structure:

> /var/www/clients/client2/web1/web/dl/pp/6250/Ya Basta! - 2002 - Lucha
>   Y Fiesta.zip
>
> /var/www/clients/client2/web1/web/dl/pp/6250/La Souris Déglinguée - 1988 - Quartier Libre.zip

When searching for the first file `(WWEgQmFzdGEhIC0gMjAwMiAtIEx1Y2hhIFkgRmllc3RhLnppcA==)` it will return the correct path.

But when searching for the second file with accents `(TGEgU291cmlzIETpZ2xpbmd16WUgLSAxOTg4IC0gUXVhcnRpZXIgTGlicmUuemlw)` it will not return any result even if the file exists.

Here's the script:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

// $encodedquery = "WWEgQmFzdGEhIC0gMjAwMiAtIEx1Y2hhIFkgRmllc3RhLnppcA==";  // query without accent = WORKS !
$encodedquery = "TGEgU291cmlzIETpZ2xpbmd16WUgLSAxOTg4IC0gUXVhcnRpZXIgTGlicmUuemlw" // query with accents = DOESNT WORKS

$decode = utf8_encode(base64_decode($encodedquery);
$search = preg_quote($decode);
echo "searching for \"$search\" ....";

        function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
            $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
            $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
            $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
            $fileList = array();
            foreach($files as $file) {
                $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
            }
            return $fileList;
        }

        $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $resultatss = rsearch($root, '/.*\/'.$search.'/');

foreach ($resultatss as $resultat) {
echo "<br>FOUND FILE = $resultat";
}
```

Comment: This is probably encoding-related. Are you sure everything is UTF-8? Why do you utf8_encode the query string? Do you know that the file system also is using UTF-8?

Comment: well the php page has utf8 headers, and if i base64_decode the query then utf8_encode it and echo the result, there is no problem with accents.

Comment: The question is: Why do you need to utf8_encode it? If your frontend IS utf-8, the value in the base64 should also be it. And there is still the issue with the file system. If it is not utf-8, then the RegexIterator will not find anything. And BTW: Do you add the utf-8 modifier to the regex?